# How do I run .sh or .bat files from Terminal?

Tags: bash, tomcat, terminal

I have a pretty basic problem here, that has happened so haphazardly to me that up until now, I've just ignored it. I downloaded tomcat web server and "Murach's Java Servlets and JSP" book is telling me to navigate to the tomcat/bin directory and start the server my typing in Terminal

$ startup

However, I get the error

```
-bash: startup: command not found
```

The relevant files in this directory are startup.sh and startup.bat. Typing both of these returns the same error message

So my questions are, what are .bat and sh files, and how do I run these files? I've read several tutorials for different languages and software programs, and some times when the tutorial says execute a bunch of files in the command line, I get a "command not found" error. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. This is perplexing to me, so what are some common solutions to solving these sort of "command not found" Terminal problems?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The `.sh` is for *nix systems and `.bat` should be for Windows. Since your example shows a bash error and you mention Terminal, I'm assuming it's OS X you're using.

In this case you should go to the folder and type:

```
./startup.sh
```

`./` just means that you should call the script located in the current directory. (Alternatively, just type the full path of the `startup.sh`). If it doesn't work then, check if `startup.sh` has execute permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation pilsetnieks. I typed what you said and it worked! onto the next installation problem.

Comment: If you have permissions denied, you may need to do `sudo ./startup.sh`

Comment: Running sudo ./scriptname.sh results in "command not found" error for some reason.

Comment: run it using sh "sh /path/to/script".
if permission is denied use 'sudo'

Comment: It is possible to run the batch file on Linux by installing, configuring, and using "Wine" package on your system. See instructions in link below: 
https://www.linux.org/threads/running-windows-batch-files-on-linux.11205/#:~:text=Batch%20files%20can%20be%20run%20by%20typing%20%22start%20FILENAME.,cmd.exe%20%2Fc%20FILENAME.

Answer (score 15):

This is because the script is not in your $PATH. Use

```
./scriptname
```

You can also copy this to one of the folders in your $PATH or alter the $PATH variable so you can always use just the script name. Take care, however, there is a reason why your current folder is not in $PATH. It might be a security risk.

If you still have problems executing the script, you might want to check its permissions - you must have execute permissions to execute it, obviously. Use

```
chmod u+x scriptname
```

A `.sh` file is a Unix shell script. A `.bat` file is a Windows batch file.

Comment: Thanks For the alternate step.
`chmod u+x scriptname`
It fixed the `Permission denied` error

Answer (score 6):

Type `bash script_name.sh` or `./script_name` in linux terminal. Before using `./script_name` make you script executeable by `sudo chmod 700 script_name` and type `script_name.bat` in windows.

Answer (score 5):

## Drag-And-Drop

Easiest way for a lazy Mac user like me: Drag-and-drop the `startup.sh` file from the Finder to the Terminal window and press Return.

To shutdown Tomcat, do the same with `shutdown.sh`.

You can delete all the `.bat` files as they are only for a Windows PC, of no use on a Mac to other Unix computer. I delete them as it makes it easier to read that folder's listing.

## File Permissions

I find that a fresh Tomcat download will not run on my Mac because of file permission restrictions throwing errors during startup. I use the `BatChmod` app which wraps a GUI around the equivelant Unix commands to reset file permissions.

## Port-Forwarding

Unix systems protect access to ports numbered under 1024. So if you want to use port 80 with Tomcat you will need to learn how to do "port-forwarding" to forward incoming requests to port 8080 where Tomcat listens by default. To do port-forwarding, you issue commands to the packet-filtering (firewall) app built into Mac OS X (and [BSD](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution)). In the old days we used [`ipfw`](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipfirewall). In Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) and later Apple is moving to a newer tool, [`pf`](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PF_(firewall)).

Answer (score 4):

Based on [IsmailS' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015449/how-do-i-run-sh-or-bat-files-from-terminal/56072911#comment87942645_17015495) the command which worked for me on OSX was:

```
sudo sh ./startup.sh
```

Answer (score 3):

On windows type either `startup` or `startup.bat`

On unix type `./startup.sh`

(assuming you are located in tomcat/bin directory)

Answer (score 1):

Type in

```
chmod 755 scriptname.sh
```

In other words, give yourself permission to run the file. I'm guessing you only have r/w permission on it.

Comment: This may not necessarily solve the problem. The error reported by @almel means that the shell searched the list of folders given by the $PATH environment variable and could not find the "startup" file. By putting "./startup", you are bypassing that search and telling the shell "Look in this folder for the script i'm trying to run"

Answer (score 0):

1. add #!bin/bash on top of the your .sh file
2. sudo chmod +x  your .sh file
3. ./your.sh file

these steps work~

Comment: `#!bin/bash` should be `#!/bin/bash`. Without the slash after the exclamation, it triggers an error: `bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion does not come from Terminal; however, this is a much easier way.

For .bat files, you can run them through Wine. Use this video to help you install it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DkS8i_blVCA. This video will explain how to install, setup and use Wine. It is as simple as opening the .bat file in Wine itself, and it will run just as it would on Windows.

Through this, you can also run .exe files, as well .sh files.

This is much simpler than trying to work out all kinds of terminal code.

Answer (score -2):

I had this problem for *.sh files in Yosemite and couldn't figure out what the correct path is for a folder on my Desktop...after some gnashing of teeth, dragged the file itself into the Terminal window; hey presto!!